# Why is Chrome not trusting imported, self-signed Root CA?

Tags: google-chrome, https, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-20.04

I receive in Chrome the error NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID even though I imported the company's Root CA into Chrome's trust store (via settings > certificates > authorities). I imported the certificate on Firefox as well and there it works fine. I even imported the certificate in the system's trust store, but I figured out that browsers use their own. I'm using Google Chrome v88.

On Windows I do not encounter this problem in Chrome.

Comment: Perhaps the Chrome versions are different? Chrome's handling of certificates evolves from version to version. For a better answer I would need to examine the certificate.

Comment: Is the website's certificate issued directly by the root CA, or is an intermediate CA being used? (Just as with public CAs, there's always an opportunity for webserver admins to misconfigure the chain, and Firefox hides the problem via intermediate caching...)

Comment: An intermediate CA is being used.

Comment: @user1686 This was the missing hint. I checked in the firefox and saw that the intermediate CA is imported as CA as well, and indeed it was. I did the same for Chrome and now it doesn't throw the error. Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit goes to [user1686](https://superuser.com/questions/1631692/why-is-chrome-not-trusting-imported-self-signed-root-ca?noredirect=1#comment2492094_1631692)'s hint about the intermediate CA. I needed to import this as well as trusted CA. Now Chrome does not complain anymore!

Comment: You should not have to manually trust an intermediate CA. You trust only the root. Then, the webserver should be configured to serve a certificate *chain* including the end-entity cert *and* the intermediate issuing CA(s). Alternatively, the client may be able to locate the intermediate itself if the end-entity cert has its URL listed in the AIA.